# Extjs4 Check-tree: tri state checkbox on nodes to summarize leaves states

Tags: checkbox, extjs4, treeview

Is it possible to incorporate tri-state checkbox in a ExtJs check tree?

By tri-state, I mean the parent node is:

- Checked if all children are checked
- Unchecked if all children are unchecked
- Grey/Filled if some children are checked but not all

Something like this:
http://shamsmi.blogspot.fr/2008/12/tri-state-checkbox-using-javascript.html

I found this to create tri-state checkbox for regular forms: 
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?138664-Ext.ux.form.TriCheckbox&p=619810

But I don't know how to apply this custom checkbox to the tree view, or even if it possible.

Any idea?